# How do i use a dependency from github in my gemspec?

Tags: ruby, gemfile, gemspecs

I currently have the following in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'voteable_mongo'#,       :github => 'kamilski81/voteable_mongo'
```

and I migrating my models into a .gemspec, but i'm not sure how this would look inside my gemspec.  I currently have:

```
s.add_dependency "voteable_mongo"
```

But this ends up using the wrong dependenty (the original one I cloned)  I would like to use my dependency.  How could i point my gemspec dependency to my github repo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated in the [gem specification](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#dependencies), the list of gems that you provide through `add_dependency` will be used to make sure those are already installed in the system during the installation process (i.e `gem install`), hence a `git` option wouldn't make sense since this doesn't trigger any additional installation of any dependencies (like `Bundler` does).

In summary: it's not possible to do what you're trying to do within a `.gemspec`